# connect ENOENT /usr/local/bin/Library/Application Support/Code/1.25.1-shared.sock

Tags: visual-studio-code

Tried installing extensions using install from welcome page, website and from the inbuilt marketplace. The welcome page and website both give me the following error message

> connect ENOENT /usr/local/bin/Library/Application Support/Code/1.25.1-shared.sock

And the marketplace doesn't even show up. It's just blank. I have Googled and can't find out what ENOENT is all about. No luck. Deleted all files and reinstalled but still the same issue. Not sure what to do. I am on versions 1.25.1. Any suggestions of what to try?

Answer (score 0):

code was not in the $PATH. Thought the installation would have taken care of this but you have to do this manually.

1. Launch VS Code, type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. search for install shell path
3. Relaunch VS Code and you should be good to go